# Javascript weird variable declaration

Tags: javascript, syntax

I was inspecting some source code until I notice this weird variable declaration which I don't understand fully.

```
let eventsEnabled : ?boolean = null;
```

What this means?

Source code from here: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.0.0-alpha.3/src/renderers/dom/fiber/ReactDOMFiber.js#L83

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React uses [Flow](https://flow.org/), a static type checker

`?boolean` is signifying that `eventsEnabled` is a [maybe type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/), meaning that it can be a boolean, or `undefined`/`null`.